# /mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file HelloWorld.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This is the Simple program in which I am just printing 'Hello World' but this error occurs everytime.

```
[Running] cd "e:\C++\Data Types\" && g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld && "e:\C++\Data Types\"HelloWorld
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file HelloWorld.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried everything but unable to produce `HelloWorld.exe` file and run this code.

Comment: This means either your antivirus has the file open or you are still running the previous executable or you have a permissions problem where your user does not have permissions to write the file. My vote is for the first one especially if you are using a different antivirus than the one that comes with the os.

Comment: @drescherjm The antivirus is stopping the `HelloWorld.exe` to run, so in order to run it I have disabled the anitvirus protecting but problem is still there.

Comment: Browse to the folder `e:\C++\Data Types\HelloWorld` and see if the file exists

Comment: My second piece of advice is to never use a path with a space in it in c++ programming.

Comment: Okay I'll rename file and try it again. The file do exits I have tried multiple times to run it.

Comment: Try to delete the executable in the windows file manager.

Comment: Problem is solved, I just uninstalled the antivirus and it worked. Actually the antivirus was treating the `.exe` file as a threat, even turning off the antivirus was not working.

Comment: Some AV have a sandbox mode that if activated can cause c++ software to not work. I have seen this with aVast. I usually have a special root folder like `c:\programming` or drive like `x:` for my code and tell my AV to ignore the whole tree.

Comment: That's a good way, I'll definitely do in this way and thank so much for helping me out.

Comment: Excluding build and source folders also improves performance of all development related tasks (searching, debugging, executing, ...). Of course, excluding these directories makes it possible for viral code compiled from source to be easily executed from that location, so don't just go compiling everything without verifying and trusting the source.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using visual studio code you can delete filename.exe (that shows below filename.cpp) then rebuilt it will work.

As shown in image

[image: As shown in image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have opened this file in the terminal. You must first kill the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your anti virus has removed the file or stoped it from executing.
Steps to resolve :

1. Copy your code and delete the file or move to step 2
2. create a new file and paste your code in it before running the new code make sure you exclude/quarantine your program folder from antivirus scans.(Or turn off antivirus or put it in silent mode)So it no longer deletes or moves your file .
3. Run the new file it should run fine now :))

[Norton file excluding steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s92n9.png)